# How to extract portion of an xmltype column

Tags: xml, extract, xmltype, getstring, instr

This is a snapshot of the xml in question

[XML Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItHod.png)

The column I need lies between  and , but this lies inside an xmltype column called Flexfiltervalue.

How do I write the sql to extract that value and it's related ConditionGroupCode

I have tried various options

1. select  t.CONDITION_GROUP_CODE as ConditionGroupCode,
   instr((t.FLEX_FILTER_VALUE).getClobVal(),''), instr((t.FLEX_FILTER_VALUE).getClobVal(),''))as clobval
   from  ZX_CONDITIONS t
   where t.condition_group_code = 'SU CC 50 1'

THIS RETURNED THE WRONG VALUE

2. SELECT t.FLEX_FILTER_VALUE.getStringVal() FROM ZX_CONDITIONS t

THIS PRODUCED AN ERROR: ORA-19011: Character string buffer too small ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 169

3. select extract(t.FLEX_FILTER_VALUE, '/').getClobVal(), <'value>'
   from  ZX_CONDITIONS t

THIS GIVES ME MISSING EXPRESISON ERROR

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your RDBMS and its version.
All within the question as text, no images.

Comment: I dont want to create a table... I have an Oracle table that is seeded and data gets populated to this table as configuration happens. I cannot insert data into this table via backend.... all data gets inserted as and when configuration happens. My desired output is to get the data lying in between <value>XXX</value>